# I am using javax api but the entitymanager is calling jakarta. persistence api

Tags: java, jpa, spring-batch, pom.xml, batch-processing

i am using javax.persistence API to create a spring batch application however the EntityManager and EntityFactory Manager are calling Jakarta persistence API.

```
package com.example.demo.Config;

import com.example.demo.Entity.Earmark;
import com.example.demo.Repository.EarmarkRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class EarmarkJobConfig {

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private final EarmarkRepository earmarkRepository;
    
    private EarmarkJobConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                             StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                             EarmarkRepository earmarkRepository) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.earmarkRepository = earmarkRepository;
    }
    
    public static EarmarkJobConfig createEarmarkJobConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                                                          StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                                          EarmarkRepository earmarkRepository) {
        return new EarmarkJobConfig(jobBuilderFactory, stepBuilderFactory, earmarkRepository);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Earmark> earmarkItemReader() {
        JpaPagingItemReader<Earmark> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager);
        reader.setQueryString("SELECT e FROM Earmark e WHERE e.status = 'Pending'");
        reader.setParameterValues(Collections.emptyMap());
        reader.setPageSize(100);
        return reader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public EarmarkItemProcessor earmarkItemProcessor() {
        return new EarmarkItemProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Earmark> earmarkItemWriter() {
        JpaItemWriter<Earmark> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();
        writer.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager);
        return writer;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step earmarkStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("earmarkStep")
                .<Earmark, Earmark>chunk(100)
                .reader(earmarkItemReader())
                .processor(earmarkItemProcessor())
                .writer(earmarkItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job earmarkJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(earmarkStep())
                .build();
    }

}
```

I tried changing pom.xml versions and tried excluding the javax api then jakarta api alternatively as well but still am getting the same error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

\<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
\<modelVersion\>4.0.0\</modelVersion\>
\<parent\>
\<groupId\>org.springframework.boot\</groupId\>
\<artifactId\>spring-boot-starter-parent\</artifactId\>
\<version\>3.0.6\</version\>
\<relativePath/\> \<!-- lookup parent from repository --\>
\</parent\>
\<groupId\>com.example\</groupId\>
\<artifactId\>demo\</artifactId\>
\<version\>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\</version\>
\<name\>JavaApplication\</name\>
\<description\>Demo project for Spring Boot\</description\>
\<properties\>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    
        <spring.boot.version>2.6.7</spring.boot.version>
        <hibernate.core.version>5.5.7</hibernate.core.version>
        <h2.version>2.1.212</h2.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <postgres.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgres.version>
        <cli.version>1.5.0</cli.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.9.1</liquibase.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
    
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>net.ldauvilaire.sample.batch.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

java: incompatible types: javax.persistence.EntityManager cannot be converted to jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Comment: Hello, jakarta is the correct one for the current Spring Boot version. Your pom.xml contains some ambiguous properties. The best way to get it done is to generate a fresh one using https://start.spring.io/ Please also note that you should install and use at least Java 17 for the current Spring Boot.

Comment: A few things are off. First, an EntityManger cannot be converted to an EntityManagerFactory anyway, regardless of the different packages - a Factory is used to obtain EntityManagers, so this is odd. Second, you didn't show where this error is coming from - that should tell you more about what is really going on. The issue initially is that the Spring version used is for Jakarta persistence units - you can't just pick one or the other as the two packages don't work together. You've then partially configured it for Jakarta, but are still using javax in your code. Use one or the other

Answer (score 1):

In addition to updating dependencies, you need to update your import statements as well to use `jakarta.*` instead of `javax.*`.

This is mentioned in the migration guide here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#dependencies-upgrade